# Where exactly is the synchronization point when using semaphores

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, semaphore, pseudocode, critical-section

I have a questions regarding the actual synchronization points in the following c - like psuedocode examples. In our slides the synchronization point is shown to occur at the point indicated below.

Two process 2 way synchronization, x and y = 0 to start

```
Process 1
signal(x);
//Marked as sync point
wait(y);

Process 2
signal(y);
//This arrow isn't as exact but appears to be near the middle again.
wait(x);
```

Now for just two process 2 way sync this seems to make sense. However, when expanding this two 3 process 3 way sync this logic seems to break down. There are no arrows given in the slide deck.

```
3 Process 3 Way Synchronization (S1, S2, S3 = 0 to start) 
Process 0
signal(S0);
signal(S0);
wait(S1);
wait(S2);

Process 1
signal(S1);
signal(S1);
wait(S0);
wait(S2);

Process 2
signal(S2);
signal(S2);
wait(S0);
wait(S1);
```

Now I find the sync point couldn't actually be between the signal and the wait. For example:

Let's so Process 0 runs first and signals S0 once. Now S0 = 1. Now let's say that before the second signal(S0) can be run that the process is interrupted and Process 1 runs next. Let's say that only one signal(S1) can be run before the process is interrupted. Now the value of S1 = 1. Now let's say that Process 2 runs next. This signal(S2) is allowed to run so S2 = 2. Now the process is not interrupted so it is allowed to continue. Wait(S0) runs which decrements S0 by 1. S0 now equals 0. However, process 2 is allowed to continue running because S0's value is not a negative value. Now wait(S1) is allowed to run and a similar thing here happens.

At this point Process 2 is done running. However Process 0 and Process 1 did not finish their signal's. If the sync point is truly in between signals and wait then this solution to 3 way 3 process sync is incorrect.

A similar issue can arise in solution for 3 process 3 way synchronization that allows each process to run more than one instance of itself at a time. Attached is that slide but I will not explain why the "middle" point in the process can't be the sync point as I already have a huge wall of text.

Please let me know which way is correct, no amount of googling has given me an answer. I will include all relevant slides.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The last one has a problem , it doesn't exclude other processes from enter the critical section while P0 signals P1 its semaphore becomes 1 and it never waits and enters CS while it P1 in turn signals P0 which makes S0 1 so it also enters the CS so finally there are two processes in the CS which defies synchronization.

Comment: @0decimal0 This was a given solution in class. Are you saying it is incorrect? I can't quite follow your reasoning. Where would you say the synchronization point is across all of these processes? At the start of the first signal, or just between the last signal and the first wait?

Comment: Even if you consider just P0 and P1 the solution seems to be wrong both the processes signal each other and therefore incrementing the S variable So they both will enter CS. wait () checks for the S variable if its `<=0` and if the condition is true the process waits but here the condition doesn't become true so it doesn't wait.

Comment: I keep looking at this. Three processes run, together they post two units to each semaphore.  The processes then wait for two units each.  They all run on.  All the rest seem to me to be UB.

Comment: Also, no C code.

Comment: TBH, the '2 way synchronization' doesn't really make sense either.

Comment: So you have issues with the third slide, it wouldn't surprise me if it's wrong. What about my main question, where is the synchronization point. Is it at the start of the first signal, or just between the last signal and the first wait?